# While using scipy.integrate.quad, increasing bound of a positive function decreases the integral! How to resolve it?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, integral

I'm using scipy.integrate to evaluate definite integrals. I've written the following code snippet to evaluate the probability density function (PDF) and cumulative distribution function (CDF) to evaluate the CDF from PDF as follows:

```
inf = 10000

def f_normal(m, tau): #normal pdf with mean np.sqrt(m- 1/2) and var 1/pi
    tmp = 1/np.sqrt(np.pi) * np.exp(  -  ( tau - np.sqrt(m- 1/2) )**2   )
    return tmp

def F_normal(m, x): #integral of f_normal from -inf to x
    return integrate.quad(lambda tau: f_normal(m, tau), -inf, x)
```

But then when I evaluate:

```
m=10    
print(f_normal(m, 10))    
print(F_normal(m, inf))
```

I'm getting `(0.0, 0.0)` for  `F_normal(m, inf)`, while I was really expecting 1. I didn't understand what's going on . Also I tried to understand the command  integrate.quad, and hence I got these strange values: while increasing the bounds decreases the definite integral of the positive function PDF and hence made no sense:

```
integrate.quad(lambda tau: f_normal(m, tau), -10, 10)
Out[30]: (1.0, 2.2977017217085778e-09)

integrate.quad(lambda tau: f_normal(m, tau), -100, 100)
Out[31]: (1.0, 8.447041410391393e-09)

integrate.quad(lambda tau: f_normal(m, tau), -1000, 1000)
Out[32]: (0.9999934640807174, 1.857441875165816e-09)

integrate.quad(lambda tau: f_normal(m, tau), -10000, 10000)
Out[33]: (5.659684283308144e-150, 1.1253180602819657e-149)

integrate.quad(lambda tau: f_normal(m, tau), -10000, 100)
Out[34]: (0.0, 0.0)

integrate.quad(lambda tau: f_normal(m, tau), -10000, 1000000)
Out[35]: (0.0, 0.0)
```

I'm a bit confused: help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `inf` is so large. You are trying to intregrate this function,

[image]

But what you are sending to the `integrate.quad` is,

[image]

The quadrature routine is very unlikely to sample that function anywhere that the value isn't essentially 0 leading to the incorrect result.

Fortunately, using `np.inf`, you can tell the algorithm that the integral is over an infinite interval and it will be smarter about looking for where the relevant behavior of the function is. This code gives the correct integral:

```
def f_normal(m, tau): #normal pdf with mean np.sqrt(m- 1/2) and var 1/pi
    tmp = 1/np.sqrt(np.pi) * np.exp(  -  ( tau - np.sqrt(m- 1/2) )**2   )
    return tmp

def F_normal(m, x): #integral of f_normal from -inf to x
    return integrate.quad(lambda tau: f_normal(m, tau), -np.inf, x)

m=10    
print(f_normal(m, m-.5))    
print(F_normal(m, np.inf))
```

Alternatively, you can integrate of a smaller finite interval around where the function is not very nearly 0. In this case the center (`np.sqrt(m-1/2)`) plus or minus 100 is reliable (where the original interval of length 20,000 is too large):

```
def f_normal(m, tau): #normal pdf with mean np.sqrt(m- 1/2) and var 1/pi
    tmp = 1/np.sqrt(np.pi) * np.exp(  -  ( tau - np.sqrt(m- 1/2) )**2   )
    return tmp

def F_normal(m, x): #integral of f_normal from -inf to x
    return integrate.quad(lambda tau: f_normal(m, tau), np.sqrt(m- 1/2)-100, x)

m=10000
print(f_normal(m, m-.5))    
print(F_normal(m, np.sqrt(m- 1/2)+100))
```

Comment: thank you your answer - indeed that does solve the problem for print(F_normal(m, np.inf)), when m is small (to be more precise, for m less than or equal to 350, where it yields that integrals's value to be near 1. But then it decreases rapidly: for $m \ge 365,$ the values are small, and tends to zero for large m, e.g. $m=3750,$ print(F_normal(m, np.inf)) gives $2.73 e^{-115}.$ I'm wondering why this is happening: the integral should always be one and not go to zero with m being large.

Comment: We can still run into the same problem as the original situation. Using infinite bounds [QUADPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUADPACK), the algorithm transforms the function to a finite interval and does quadrature there. If the transformed function is roughly 0 at all the quadrature points, the algorithm never finds any relevant points to compute the result. Moving the mean away from the origin compresses the support in the transformed domain and makes this issue more common. Keeping the support near the origin (where the transformation is less pronounced) is going to be more reliable.

Comment: thanks again! But for my problem, I really need to let m  go to infinity, so is there really no way around so that I can obtain correct values for print(F_normal(m, x)) for such large m and any x?

Comment: If you know something about the support of your pdf, a finite interval will work if it is small enough. For example, your original code works with inf = 20. Using `m=10000`, I get a correct integral using finite bounds of 0 and 200. But if you don't know anything about the support of the function, then quadrature is inevitably going to fail at some point: the algorithm is going to sample points that are all 0 and miss the portion of the line where the function is doing something interesting.

Comment: Well even though technically the support of the pdf is the whole real line (i.e. all real numbers), away from the mean sqrt(m-0.5), pdf becomes exponentially small. So I think to obtain the CDF from the PDF, I can choose a suitable interval around sqrt(m-0.5) and then integrate over this to obtain the CDF. For example, I tried:

def F_normal(m, x): #integral of f_normal from -inf to x
    return integrate.quad(lambda tau: f_normal(m, tau), np.sqrt(m- 1/2)-25, x)

and then 

m=100000000000
print(F_normal(m, np.sqrt(m- 1/2) + 25))

and it gave me almost 1.

Comment: Yeah, I was using roughly sqrt(m-1/2) +/- 100 as the integration bounds and it seems to get close to numerical precision for a large range of m values.

Comment: thanks again! I asked a related question here today. if you've some time, I'd appreciate if you could please take a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727540/how-to-modify-the-following-code-to-make-it-run-faster-and-give-correct-values-f?noredirect=1#comment112696214_63727540 Any idea to solve the problem is welcome!